# What is this? (Unknown box in Wordpress Theme)

Tags: css, wordpress

I can't identify what the tip of [the box just under the pink bar](http://glamourunderground.com) is. Obviously I need to make it the same width as the wrapper.

[image]

I've tried using 'inspect element' in Chrome, but it just jumps to the wrapper or the bar. Maybe some Wordpress users will know..?

Thanks,

Tara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a background image. [url](http://www.glamourunderground.com/wp-content/themes/primus/primus/images/bg.jpg)

Either increase the size of the background image or decrease the width of your divs like #wrapper and all that has hard coded widths.